# How can I add styles to elements inside p-dialog?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I tried to add styles to elements inside the `p-dialog` element but looks like the styles don't get applied due to Angular's CSS encapsulation.

How can I add styles to the elements inside the `p-dialog` without changing my app's CSS encapsulation properties?

**Edit -**

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="788" [responsive]="false">
    <p-header style="float:left">
        New Item
    </p-header> 

    <div style="float:left;">
    </div>
    ...
    ...


    <p-footer>
        <button type="button" (click)="display=false">Save</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="display=false">Cancel</button>
    </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

I want to apply styles to the `Save`and `Cancel` buttons. and the content in the `p-dialog`.

Comment: [ngStyle]="{'color': 'blue'}"  or something

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Styling the `<p-dialog>`

One way of doing it is with inline styling the `<p-dialog>` tag using the brackets `[]`:

```
<p-dialog [style]="{'color':'red'}"></p-dialog>
```

You can also style your `p-dialog` element by setting the `styleClass` attribute:

```
<p-dialog styleClass="myClass"></p-dialog>
```

With CSS you select it with its class name:

```
.myClass {
   color: red;
}
```

---

## Styling child elements

You can style elements that are contained in the `p-dialog` tags like any other HTML elements: simply add a class attribute to the child element:

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="788" [responsive]="false">
    <p-header class="dialogHeader">
        New Item
    </p-header>
</p-dialog>
```

and select it with the selector in CSS:

```
.dialogHeader {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to style the `p-dialog` element itself, I want to style the child elements inside the `p-dialog` element.

Comment: @pratik Ok, you can set the `styleClass` attribute on the child elements as well and select in your stylesheet. Do you need the code?

Comment: The code is not needed. I was not aware that we can set `styleClass` for child elements. I'll try doing that.

Comment: I tried using `styleClass` on the child elements, and it doesn't seem to work. The styles are not being applied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151322/discussion-between-pratik-and-ivan).